# How to inline a function from libc with gcc?

Tags: gcc, inline, mips

I'm having the following problem: my software is causing a deadlock and the only clue that I have about its origin is a primitive stack trace with only 8 levels provided by my chipset for situations like this.

However, my stack trace is something like:

```
memset
memset
memset
memset
memset
memset
memset
memset
```

I want to remove memset out of my way to see which function is causing this mess. If I ask gcc to inline memset, it will complain stating that I don't have the function body for it.

So, is there a way to inline memset? Does anyone have any other idea about debugging this problem?

**EDIT**

I've already tried to replace memset with a dumb implementation using a **for**, but this made my software behave strangely and other problems appear that prevents me from getting to the deadlock.

**EDIT**

By the way, I'm using the MIPS arch. I'm not an MIPS assembly expert, so I've made a dumb attempt at getting the disassembled code for memset and inserting in the body of a C function. I got different instructions from objdump -d and gdb disassemble, so I've tried with both of them. Here are the functions that I've created:

```
void * memset(void * str_a, int ch, size_t count) {
    asm("mov    #12,r0");
    asm("cmp/gt r6,r0");
    asm("mov    r4,r0");
    asm("bt.s   30 <.L_dup_bytes+0x18>");
    asm("add    r4,r6");
    asm("tst    #3,r0");
    asm("bt.s   18 <.L_dup_bytes>");
    asm("extu.b r5,r5");
    asm("mov.b  r5,@r0");
    asm("add    #1,r0");
    asm("tst    #3,r0");
    asm("bf 10 <_memset+0x10>");
}

void * memset(void * str_a, int ch, size_t count) {
    asm("mov    #12,r0");
    asm("cmp/gt r6,r0");
    asm("mov    r4,r0");
    asm("bt.s   0x8163682c <memset+48>");
    asm("add    r4,r6");
    asm("tst    #3,r0");
    asm("bt.s   0x81636814 <memset+24>");
    asm("extu.b r5,r5");
    asm("mov.b  r5,@r0");
    asm("add    #1,r0");
    asm("tst    #3,r0");
    asm("bf 0x8163680c <memset+16>");
    asm("swap.b r5,r2");
    asm("or r2,r5");
    asm("swap.w r5,r2");
    asm("or r2,r5");
    asm("add    #-16,r6");
    asm("nop    ");
    asm("mov.l  r5,@r0");
    asm("cmp/hs r6,r0");
    asm("mov.l  r5,@(4,r0)");
    asm("bf.s   0x81636820 <memset+36>");
    asm("add    #8,r0");
    asm("add    #16,r6");
    asm("cmp/eq r6,r0");
    asm("bt 0x81636838 <memset+60>");
    asm("mov.b  r5,@r0");
    asm("add    #1,r0");
    asm("cmp/eq r6,r0");
    asm("bf 0x81636830 <memset+52>");
    asm("rts    ");
    asm("mov    r4,r0");
}
```

This gave me the following errors:

First memset:

```
/tmp/ccAuFFap.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccAuFFap.s:3457: Warning: missing operand; zero assumed
/tmp/ccAuFFap.s:3469: Warning: missing operand; zero assumed
/tmp/ccAuFFap.s:3489: Warning: missing operand; zero assumed
/tmp/ccAuFFap.s:3457: Error: displacement to defined symbol .L0 overflows 8-bit field
/tmp/ccAuFFap.s:3469: Error: displacement to undefined symbol .L0 overflows 8-bit field 
/tmp/ccAuFFap.s:3489: Error: displacement to defined symbol .L0 overflows 8-bit field
```

Second memset:

```
/tmp/cctCDgi5.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cctCDgi5.s:3457: Warning: missing operand; zero assumed
/tmp/cctCDgi5.s:3469: Warning: missing operand; zero assumed
/tmp/cctCDgi5.s:3489: Warning: missing operand; zero assumed
/tmp/cctCDgi5.s:3529: Warning: missing operand; zero assumed
/tmp/cctCDgi5.s:3545: Warning: missing operand; zero assumed
/tmp/cctCDgi5.s:3561: Warning: missing operand; zero assumed
/tmp/cctCDgi5.s:3457: Error: displacement to defined symbol .L0 overflows 8-bit field
/tmp/cctCDgi5.s:3469: Error: displacement to defined symbol .L0 overflows 8-bit field
/tmp/cctCDgi5.s:3489: Error: displacement to defined symbol .L0 overflows 8-bit field
/tmp/cctCDgi5.s:3529: Error: displacement to defined symbol .L0 overflows 8-bit field
/tmp/cctCDgi5.s:3545: Error: displacement to defined symbol .L0 overflows 8-bit field
/tmp/cctCDgi5.s:3561: Error: displacement to defined symbol .L0 overflows 8-bit field
```

Can someone help with those errors?

**EDIT**

Tried another version with the source code from :

```
void * memset(void * str_a, int ch, size_t count) {    
    asm("slti    t1, a2, 8               ");
    asm("bne     t1, zero, L(last8)");
    asm("move    v0, a0                  ");
    asm("beq     a1, zero, L(ueven)      ");
    asm("andi    a1, 0xff                ");
    asm("sll     t0, a1, 8");
    asm("or      a1, t0");
    asm("sll     t0, a1, 16");
    asm("or      a1, t0                  ");
    asm("L(ueven):       ");
    asm("subu    t0, zero, a0            ");
    asm("andi    t0, 0x3");
    asm("beq     t0, zero, L(chkw)");
    asm("subu    a2, t0");
    asm("SWHI    a1, 0(a0)               ");
    asm("addu    a0, t0                  ");
    asm("L(chkw):        ");
    asm("andi    t0, a2, 0x7             ");
    asm("beq     t0, a2, L(chkl)");
    asm("subu    a3, a2, t0");
    asm("addu    a3, a0                  ");
    asm("move    a2, t0                  ");
    asm("L(loopw):       ");
    asm("addiu   a0, 8                   ");
    asm("sw      a1, -8(a0)");
    asm("bne     a0, a3, L(loopw)");
    asm("sw      a1, -4(a0)");
    asm("L(chkl):        ");
    asm("andi    t0, a2, 0x4             ");
    asm("beq     t0, zero, L(last8)      ");
    asm("subu    a2, t0");
    asm("sw      a1, 0(a0)               ");
    asm("addiu   a0, 4");
    asm("L(last8):       ");
    asm("blez    a2, L(exit)             ");
    asm("addu    a3, a2, a0              ");
    asm("L(lst8l):       ");
    asm("addiu   a0, 1");
    asm("bne     a0, a3, L(lst8l)");
    asm("sb      a1, -1(a0)");
    asm("L(exit):        ");
    asm("j       ra                      ");
    asm("nop");
}
```

Here are the errors this time:

```
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5131: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5135: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5139: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5143: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5147: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5151: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5155: Error: invalid operands for opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5159: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5163: Error: invalid operands for opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5167: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5171: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5175: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5179: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5183: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5187: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5191: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5195: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5199: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5203: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5207: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5211: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5215: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5219: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5223: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5227: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5231: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5235: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5239: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5243: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5247: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5251: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5255: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5259: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5263: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5267: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5271: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5275: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5279: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5283: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5287: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5291: Error: unknown opcode
/tmp/ccuyfGW5.s:5295: Error: unknown opcode
```

**EDIT**

The problem was indeed related to stack corruption, but I'll let this question here to see if anyone knows the answer about how to get the disassembled code from a subroutine and put it back into a C function body for inlining.

Comment: Maybe implement your own memset so the compiler can inline? If the source isn't available, you can also disassemble the memset call and copy that implementation and make it available to the compiler.

Comment: I've already tried with a dumb implementation using a for. Can you post an example of disassembling and making it available to the compiler?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using some sort of debugger like `gdb` to get that stacktrace. Just put a breakpoint on any `memset` call and trace into it. The idea is to get the dissembled instructions. Afterwards, you could use `__asm` and inline it in your C source or manually reverse engineer it back to some version of C code.

Comment: You don't have to examine the binary, you can consult the original source code https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc-ports.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/mips/memset.S;h=30a0ba44e78da201583cca2ac77ed8d0a074b26b;hb=a20c2b3c87aebc7d4b090c622d36480263b80042

Comment: The stack trace with 8 levels of `memset()` on it does not make sense.  You'd need `memset()` to call itself 7 times (at least) to get that.  So, your problem is likely that you have some other violent abuse of the stack, and something is copying data over the stack so it looks a bit like multiple calls to `memset()`.  Given the repeated appearance of `memset()`, you are likely mis-initializing a stack-allocated array, maybe using `sizeof(array)` instead of `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` to initialize the elements and trampling out of bounds. [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) might help.

Comment: I guess you are right, Jonathan. But I'll leave the question open if someone really needs to do this. However, no matter what is the address of memset, it always appear on the stack. And I don't think that this stack trace is "thread safe", so I might be seeing several tasks together there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither `gdb` nor `objdump` produce code that the `gcc` inline MIPS assembler will accept. I'm not aware of any tool that automatically fixes the syntax, so manual correction of the assembler syntax will be needed. You would also need to tell `gcc` which registers and/or memory will get altered by the inline asm code. All of this is not a trivial task.

If you had `C` source code,the `-S` option of `gcc` produces almost syntactically correct MIPS assembler, but even that requires some manual editing.

Comment: Ok! I won't put more energy on this right now and this answer seems to put any person looking for this in the right track. Thanks!