# How to download a file from godbolt?

Tags: c, linux, godbolt

I'd like to download the shared library `libc.so.6` from godbolt. The site is running `GNU libc version: 2.31` and I downloaded that package from https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libc/glibc-2.31.tar.xz and rebuilt the shared object. But, things didn't go well and I suspect there's a difference between godbolt's shared object and mine, so I'd rather download it directly from godbolt.

Is there a way to chunk the output then assemble them locally to produce the `libc.so.6` binary?

Currently it produces this `[Truncated]` output

```
Program returned: 143
Program stdout
0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x03 0x00 ... [Truncated]
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/s5xbEb6Kq)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    FILE *libc_file = fopen("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", "rb");
    uint8_t byte;
    while (fread(&byte, 1, 1, libc_file) == 1) {
        printf("0x%02X ", byte);
    }
    fclose(libc_file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sure you can "chunk" it. Write a bunch of programs that will read and print different parts of the file and run them separately. The whole exercise is rather questionable though.

Comment: it is too long for godbolt. It will not output so much information as it would kill the server if many users would like to abuse it

Comment: FWIW, you can look up godbolt's [output truncation behavior in its source](https://github.com/compiler-explorer/compiler-explorer/blob/0dbb492e453edcb4afa928cc86b5de74066b25cc/lib/exec.ts#L126). Your output looks to be precisely `32768 == 2**15` characters long, which seems like a sensible maximum length. Curiously this is less than the default max length given in the code of `2**20`, so I guess the live web instance overrides it with a smaller value in `ExecutionOptions`.

Comment: _"things didn't go well and I suspect there's a difference between godbolt's shared object and mine"_ - what makes you think that the version running in compiler explorer would fit in your environment? What was it that _"didn't go well"_ ?

Comment: Ted's comments makes sense, since the compiler explorer arena is most likely not relatable to my build on ubuntu. "Things not going well" means I ran into build errors such as `collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`. Thanks!

Comment: I find it hard to believe that `ld` would exit with a non-zero code without first issuing a pertinent error message.

Comment: @vengy What is the full linker error you get? _"undefined reference ... something ..."_?

Comment: I reset the build and was able to generate the libc.so.6 Thanks. :)

Comment: Can't hurt to read this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56246283/620097 . Good luck.